# how can i set up the ckan datastore extension

Tags: ckan

It's my first time to install ckan2.2 in ubuntu12.04.
I followed the document to set up the datastore,but when I executed command line "paster datastore set-permissions postgres -c xxxx/development.ini",it was failed and returned

```
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'auth_audit_exempt'
```

I have configed "ckan.datastore.write_url" and "ckan.datastore.read_url",I'm sure the password is right.
If i skip this set up, i can not run the ckan.

```
 sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) FATAL:  role "datastore_default" is not permitted to log in
 None None
```

Can anyone help me ??

**at last, i have solved this problem...**

just login the database "datastore_default" with superuser "postgres",and **"alter role datastore_default login;"**

wtf...

Comment: You should close this as it seems you've found the solution - you might also want to add the answer to your own question as an actual answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you created a bad user.
Can you sure you created the user command is:
sudo -u postgres createuser -S -D -R -P ckan_default .
The optional -S -D -R -P must be capital.